# Grammar rules governing a phrase from the US Constitution:

Tags: commas, syntactic-analysis, semantics

The U.S. Constitution, Article II, Section 1, Paragraph 5 reads

> No person except a natural born citizen, or a citizen of the United States, at the time of the adoption of this Constitution, shall be eligible to the office of President; neither shall any person be eligible to that office who shall not have attained to the age of thirty five years, and been fourteen Years a resident within the United States.

A friend is misinterpreting the opening noun phrase and taking the sentence to mean that only a person who was either a natural born citizen or citizen at the time of the adoption of the Constitution is eligible to become president. In other words, no one other than those select individuals who were alive during the adoption can be president. I know the notion is odd. But I don't know the specific technical reason to explain to him why he is incorrect.

Comment: The reason are, first, that his interpretation is nonsensical, and second, that English writers put in many more commas, when the Constitution was written, so that you can't interpret commas as meaning the same thing, that they would mean today. Take out the second comma and see what it means then.

Comment: From a grammatical point of view "at the time of ..." may refer either to "citizen of US" or to "natural born citizen or citizen of the US". But as highlighted by @PeterShor, the second interpretation is odd in the context of the text.

Comment: Though the wording is ambiguous, the clear intent is "nobody who wasn't a U.S. citizen at birth can ever be President, except for us, the authors, and our peers, because many of us were born British."

Comment: @Doug: actually, when it was written, the only people who were citizens of the U.S. at birth would have been much younger than thirty-five, and so were disqualified for that reason.

Comment: @PeterShor Has the Supreme Court yet ruled whether *natural born citizen* means someone born with US nationality, or  somebody actually born within the geographical limits of the United States? I know it was an issue with regard to John McCain, who was born in Panama - but in the US military-controlled zone.

Comment: @WS2 The Supreme Court has never ruled what *natural born* means, and it's not even clear that anyone would have standing to bring a case in which the Court would have the opportunity.  A US national is different from a US citizen, but what we don't know is whether someone naturalized at birth is natural born.  Neither do we know the extent of those geographical limits.  McCain was not naturalized at birth.  Congress erred in writing the law for Zonian parents and corrected it later, making McCain's citizenship retroactive to his brith.

Comment: @deadrat So would any petitioner have to wait for a supposed non-natural-born to be elected, and then challenge his right to be invested as President?

Comment: @WS2 Absolutely.  Federal courts may hear only actual controversies, which means no advisory opinions.  So until a non-natural born person attains the office (whatever that means -- elected? certified by Congress? installed?), there's no actual damage to anyone, so no one may bring suit for relief.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's exactly what it *is* saying.  As you say, nobody currently alive is therefore eligible.

What this demonstrates is that **the consititution is not the laws**.  Instead, the laws are derived from the constitution, in a common-sense way, to attempt to capture the important aspects of the constitution.  The finer details of what exactly is meant by the "important aspects" has provided a lot of lawyers with a lot of work and has led to various amendmentments, clarifications, etc.

Comment: But did it mean that in 1789, or have the rules of comma usage changed since the 18th century, so that it only means that using the current rules for commas?

Comment: I can't see how "the rules of comma usage" could possibly affect the meaning of that sentence.

Comment: So you think in this sentence: *"No person except a natural born citizen, or a citizen of the United States at the time of the adoption of this Constitution, shall be eligible to the office of President,"* the phrase *"at the time of adaption ..."* also applies to natural born citizens?

Comment: If we assume (and i think this is an implicit assumption in the consitution) that all presidential candidates need to actually **exist** at the same point in time at which they want to become president then i don't see what difference it makes.

Answer (score 1):

Joseph Story served on the Supreme Court from 1811 to 1845. In 1833, he explained the meaning:

> It is indispensable, too, that the president should be a natural born
>   citizen of the United States; or a citizen at the adoption of the
>   constitution, and for fourteen years before his election. This
>   permission of a naturalized citizen to become president is an
>   exception from the great fundamental policy of all governments, to
>   exclude foreign influence from their executive councils and duties. It
>   was doubtless introduced (for it has now become by lapse of time
>   merely nominal, and will soon become wholly extinct) out of respect to
>   those distinguished revolutionary patriots, who were born in a foreign
>   land, and yet had entitled themselves to high honours in their adopted
>   country.

Answer (score 0):

An historical argument is more apropos than a grammatical one in this case.  Yes, the conventions regrading punctuation have changed since the the 1700's.  Was the use of commas a political choice?  Could alternative punctuation like the use of parentheses or even a semicolon implied a semantic subordination in the language that could have been exploited by future opportunists?  Who knows?

Here's a bit I found about pre-constitutional presidency that gave me a chuckle and a bit of perspective:

- " All the members of Congress ran for their lives, leaving Hanson as the only guy left running the government. He somehow managed to calm the troops down and hold the country together. If he had failed, the government would have fallen almost immediately and everyone would have been bowing to King Washington."

http://www.constitution.org/hist/first8pres.htm

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of this provision cannot be discerned by treating it as an isolated exercise in punctuation and grammar.  The Supreme Court will interpret the clause in light of the rules of statutory construction, which are summed up nicely in the article ["Rules and Aids in Statutory Construction"](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1105492?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) published in the November 1915 issue of the *Virginia Law Review*.  Two of these rules follow.  (The emphasis is mine.)

> 4. The rules of grammar are presumed to be known to the legislature and are to be followed in the construction of a statute,
>      **unless** the
>      legislative intent be violated, or inconvenience or **absurdity results**.
>      While **punctuation is no part of a statute and not controlling upon the
>      court**, it is to be followed with the above qualification.
>
> 12. A statute is to be construed to **avoid** ... injustice, inconvenience an **absurdity**